# How do I add behavior to Confide to allow me to have disabled flags on a user account?

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering how I could add a check during user login with Confide, to check if a user account is flagged as disabled?

In the Confide class there's the following function:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log a user into the application with
 * password and identity field(s), usually email or username.
 *
 * @param  array $credentials
 * @param  bool $confirmed_only
 * @param  mixed $identity_columns
 * @return boolean Success
 */
public function logAttempt( $credentials, $confirmed_only = false, $identity_columns = array() )
{
    // If identity columns is not provided, use all columns of credentials
    // except password and remember.
    if(empty($identity_columns))
    {
        $identity_columns = array_diff(
            array_keys($credentials),
            array('password','remember')
        );
    }

    // Check for throttle limit then log-in
    if(! $this->reachedThrottleLimit( $credentials ) )
    {
        $user = $this->repo->getUserByIdentity($credentials, $identity_columns);

        if(
            $user &&
            ($user->confirmed || ! $confirmed_only ) &&
            $this->app['hash']->check(
                $credentials['password'],
                $user->password
            )
        )
        {
            $remember = isset($credentials['remember']) ? $credentials['remember'] : false;

            $this->app['auth']->login( $user, $remember );
            return true;
        }
    }

    $this->throttleCount( $credentials );

    return false;
}
```

All I would really like to do is add a check for `$user->disabled` which is a field I created. Short of extending and registering a new service provider, does anyone know of another way of doing this?

Comment: I'm looking to do this exact thing, did you ever find an elegant solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But if you add a soft-delete trait to the user model, you can delete them and that ends up serving the same purpose. You can then pull all the deleted ones as an admin by calling them with `withTrashed()`.